# Fancybox Vimeo shows a white screen on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have added a vimeo popup to my home page. When you click play the box shows up but its an all white box. No error messages popup there or in dreamweaver.I am viewing this in google chrome, its a white box. In Safari it continues to load and video never shows. When I change the link to a youtube video...it works just fine. Here is the code.

```
`<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://vimeo.com/72441143"><img src="../MSK-Site/Graphics/play.png" style="position:fixed; left:550px; bottom:450px;" /></a>`
```

here is the jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        width   :   '70%',
        height  :   '70%'
        });
    });
```

---

Ok This is what I have in response to your answer- JFK

```
<script type="text/javascript"    
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../MSK-Site/js/fancy-   
box/source/jquery.fancybox.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../MSK-Site/js/fancy-
box/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../MSK-Site/js/fancy-
box/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

and

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/72441143?    
autoplay=1"><img src="../MSK-Site/Graphics/play.png" style="position:fixed; left:550px;   
bottom:450px;" /></a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        width: '70%',
        height: '70%',
        helpers: {
            media: {}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Am i posting incorrectly? I see people view my answer but don't answer. Am i missing something from my post? First time doing this.

Comment: Your post is OK but people may reply only if they know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't contain Vimeo inside an `iframe` as you can see in this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3DMQN/). Most likely the are using [x-frame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/X-Frame-Options) options to avoid that.

If you want to watch a Vimeo's videos inside an `iframe` using fancybox then you have two options :

---

1). Change the format of your *html* to use the Vimeo's `player` within the `href` of your anchor like :

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://player.vimeo.com/video/72441143?autoplay=1">vimeo</a>
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4Eghc/)**

---

2). Use fancybox's Media Helper (recommended)

Leave your html anchor as is

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="http://vimeo.com/72441143">vimeo</a>
```

then load the fancybox's Media Helper js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="pathTofancybox/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

and change your script to load the helper like :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        width: '70%',
        height: '70%',
        helpers: {
            media: {}
        }
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sKPwy/)**

Comment: Tried both of these and they open the video in a new window. The video is fullscreen. How do i add the code to show you?

Comment: well, I created jsfiddle to demonstrate it works either way. You may be missing to load properly the js or css files or have another script triggering a js error that blocks fancybox from working. Can you share a link?